# Convergence to infinity of distinct partial sums

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am currently working what I thought would be a simple exercise, but am actually having trouble getting any foothold.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $\{X_{n,k}\mid 1\leq k\leq n\}$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $0\leq X_{n,k}\leq M<\infty$ (where $M$ is the same constant for all $n$ and $k$), and let $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{n,k}$. Show that if $\mu_{n}:=\mathbb{E}S_{n}$ converges to infinity, then for all $N>0$ we have that $\mathbb{P}(S_{n}>N)\rightarrow 1$.

We are given the hint that it is sufficient to show that $\mathbb{P}(S_{n}\in(\frac{\mu_{n}}{2},\frac{3\mu_{n}}{2}))\rightarrow 1$), which is what I have been trying to show. However, my attempts having been revolving around using Markov's inequality which is not giving me anything useful.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint / Possible approach...  use [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)

More details, if desired:

- Using $0 \le X_{n,k} \le M$ show that $Var(X_{n,k})$ is bounded.
- Using $S_n = $ sum of i.i.d. variables, show that $Var(S_n)$ goes as ${n}$ and therefore standard deviation $\sigma$ goes as $\sqrt{n}$.
- Finally, use [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) to show $P(|S_n - \mu_n| > {\mu_n \over 2}) \to 0$.

Disclaimer: I haven't worked through all the details, so apologies in advance if this turns out not to work.  :)

Comment: I've been able to conclude that $\mathbb{P}(|S_{n}-\mu_{n}|>\mu_{n}/2)\rightarrow 0$ in the way you suggested, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: $S_n \in [{\mu_n \over 2}, {3 \mu_n \over 2}] \iff |S_n - \mu_n| \le {\mu_n \over 2} \iff NOT (|S_n - \mu_n| > {\mu_n \over 2}|)$

Comment: Haha, of course. Thank you for the clarification.